# using find command to find string that is not at the beggining or end of a line

Tags: linux, shell, find

So I know how to find strings in a filename that are at the end or the beginning of the line using the asterisk character accordingly. Problem is I can't find a way to find a string *anywhere* in the filename. So while a command like this:

find -name foo

will only match a file named foo and ones using the asterisk will only match ones at the end or beginning of the filename, I want an expression that will find "foo" in a filename like "foobar".

Answer (score 4):

asterisk before and after foo:

```
find . -name "*foo*"
```

Comment: you are a true guru :)